# Drag and Drop links in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dojo

I have links on my page, and I want to make a copy of them to another div doing a drag.

I have already seen How to [Drag and Drop in JavaScript](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/mk/column2/index.html) and [Cross Browser HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/01/10/cross-browser-html5-drag-and-drop/), but they don't work properly. When the draggable object is a link it's not possible to drag.

I want something simple: to drag the link and get the information in the other div.

I'm using dojo 1.4.3, but the drag and drop is not compatible with IE9. Thus, I cannot use it. The version of dojo cannot be changed, and IE7-9, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari compatibility is required.

I can't use jQuery.

Comment: you can't use jquery but you add jquery tag?

Comment: Ok, sorry. Thanks for editing

Comment: The soon to be released dojo 1.7 finally adds support for IE9, not that it helps you.  The user experience for clicking and holding on a link then dragging and have it not take you to the link's location is a little weird.  Maybe you could add a 'handle' image of sorts that the user uses to drag the link and the 'handle' around?

Comment: Dojo 1.6.1 also supports IE9.  @jaapaurelio, you should expand your question to explain exactly where you run into difficulty writing DnD code for links... which part does not work?  Also, have you been able to identify the Dojo failure on IE9?  If it's trivial enough, you may be able to monkeypatch Dojo or backport a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can suggest my **REDIPS.drag** library that is based on dragging DIV elements across tables. Dragging layout is defined with table cells and every DIV element with class="drag" will become drag-able.

DIV element can contain any HTML content like another table or a link. It's also possible to clone DIV elements - as you need to copy original links.

Here is link to the library with live demo (please pay attention to the orange DIV element with *Smile* text - *Smile* is a link):

http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/